# How to resize a table using Insert Table in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In Draw.io perform the following:

1. In "Search Shapes" enter "Table" use ENTER key to search.
2. Pick the first green color scheme table by selecting, dragging and dropping on canvas.
3. Double-click on the table to get the "Table object in Mockup Text" menu.
4. Select "Table" icon under Insert.
5. Resize the table from 3x5 to 3x6.

Notice that instead of resizing the table it becomes unusable.
[image]

How do I resize the table using this tool or how is this tool desined to be used?